# Is there a way with VBA to capture when a PowerPoint slide is DELETED

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I already have code with runs when a PowerPoint slide is added to a presentation but I cannot find a way to capture when a slide is deleted. I wondered if anyone had any ideas please?

I've looked through the WithEvents list but cannot find one that appears right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such event in PowerPoint :-(

How the code works

- implement a slide counter
- whenever `SlideSelectionChanged` fires, current slides count is compared to the counter - if less at least one slide must have been deleted. `SlideSelectionChanged` fires when deleting a slide as a different slide gets selected after deletion.

Put this code into your Application class.

```vb
Private WithEvents objApp As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Set objApp = Application
On Error Resume Next
    'When addin starts there is no activepresentation
    If Application.Presentations.Count > 0 Then
        If Not ActivePresentation Is Nothing Then
            initSlideCounter ActivePresentation
        End If
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Private Sub initSlideCounter(p As Presentation)
p.Tags.Add "CNTSLIDES", p.Slides.Count
End Sub

Private Property Get SlideCounter(p As Presentation) As Long
On Error Resume Next
SlideCounter = p.Tags("CNTSLIDES")
If Err <> 0 Then
    initSlideCounter p
    SlideCounter = p.Tags("CNTSLIDES")
End If
On Error GoTo 0
End Property

Private Sub objApp_SlideSelectionChanged(ByVal SldRange As SlideRange)
Dim p As Presentation: Set p = SldRange.Parent

If p.Slides.Count < SlideCounter(p) Then
    MsgBox "at least one slide has been deleted"
    initSlideCounter p    'slide deleted
End If

End Sub

Private Sub objApp_NewPresentation(ByVal Pres As Presentation)
initSlideCounter Pres
End Sub

Private Sub objApp_PresentationOpen(ByVal Pres As Presentation)
initSlideCounter Pres
End Sub

Private Sub objApp_PresentationNewSlide(ByVal sld As Slide)
initSlideCounter sld.Parent
End Sub
```